# Offset to show/hide navigation menu on page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, offset

Trying to make offset to show/hide navigation menu on page scroll position 100px. It's show/hide navigation in one mouse scroll, i have set `lastScroll = 0` to `lastScroll = 100` but not works.

**Jquery:** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fbr320y/1/)

```
// Script
lastScroll = 0;
$(window).on('scroll',function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll === 0){
        $(".nav").removeClass("darkHeader");
    } else if(lastScroll - scroll > 0) {
        $(".nav").addClass("darkHeader");
    } else {
        $(".nav").removeClass("darkHeader");
    }
    lastScroll = scroll;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
Sticky top navigation bar
</div>
<div class="wrap">
<h3>Some filler text</h3>
Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet mollit ball tip occaecat brisket cupidatat meatball capicola. Capicola rump turducken, elit shankle cupidatat pastrami duis fatback. Sint occaecat kielbasa labore pastrami corned beef. Sunt swine bacon, fugiat dolor aute anim jerky nostrud et venison shankle consectetur boudin landjaeger.
Pork chop sed turkey aute, duis corned beef pariatur short loin proident culpa. Capicola filet mignon fugiat corned beef shank ea, commodo doner adipisicing eu salami. Doner laboris pariatur beef ribs non id. Andouille eu meatball consectetur ham hock. Ea dolore cillum cow pork loin aliquip leberkas id est corned beef dolore t-bone. In salami jerky cupidatat et.
</div>
```

So how to show/hide navigation in mouse scroll position 100px. Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fbr320y/1/).

I mean it's only show navigation menu when you scroll up page and it happen in right way. But i want show after scroll up page 100px, means not showing right way, want show and hide after 100px scroll up page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you want to do? When exactly do you want the navbar to have the class of 'darkHeader'? When exactly do you want to hide it? Try to break the description into sections: 1) when scroll is < 100px 2) when scroll is > 100px

Comment: I don't really understand your problem..could you brief it.?

Comment: @dangor - Yes sure, It's show/hide navigation in 1 mouse scroll, trying to show/hide in 3 mouse scroll or on 100px position.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by '1 mouse scroll'? Try to express the values in pixels...

Comment: I mean show/hide navigation is ok, but i want to show/hide after 100px of page scroll position.

Comment: That's a bit unclear... Do you want to show it after 100px or do you want to hide it after 100px?

Comment: Hi want Both,  when show and hide.

Comment: Can you be more precise on what do you want pls ?

Comment: @SofieneDJEBALI  - Thanks, Detail is: My old hide & showing should not change it's only show navigation menu when you scroll up page and it happen in right way. But i want show after scroll up page 100px, means not showing right way, want showing after 100px scroll up page. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. Btw, medium.com does this pretty well. They even wrote a post on how they did it. You might want to check it out in case you really want to polish off your solution:

https://medium.com/@mariusc23/hide-header-on-scroll-down-show-on-scroll-up-67bbaae9a78c

```
var lastScroll = 0;
var scrollUpStart = 0;
$(window).on('scroll',function() {

    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll === 0){
        // we are at the top
        $(".nav").removeClass("darkHeader");
    } else if(lastScroll > scroll) {
        // we are scrolling up

        // we check if we have started scrolling up already
        if (scrollUpStart < scroll) {
            // if we just started scrolling up, we set 
            // the scrollUpStart to the current scroll value
            scrollUpStart = scroll;
        }

        // if we continue scrolling up, the difference between 
        // scrollUpStart and scroll will eventually reach a 100px
        if (scrollUpStart - scroll > 100) {
            $(".nav").addClass("darkHeader");
        }

    } else {
        // we are scrolling down
        // reset scrollUpStart
        scrollUpStart = 0;
        $(".nav").removeClass("darkHeader");
    }
    lastScroll = scroll;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but .nav not hiding like my previous way, i want to keep old hiding or showing, and your 100 offset not working. Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/9fbr320y/17/

Comment: It's not working because you changed your original fiddle. Originally you had `position:fixed` on the `darkHeader` class and not the `nav` class:
http://jsfiddle.net/9fbr320y/1/

In your second fiddle, you put the `position: fixed` on the `nav` class and not the `darkHeader` class:

Comment: This is your original fiddle, updated with my answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/9fbr320y/18/

Comment: Hi, it still offset 0px , it should show & hide on 100px position or on 3 time mouse scroll.

Comment: I give up, still don't understand what you want exactly.

Comment: Ok, Detail is: My old hide & showing should not change it's only show navigation menu when you scroll up page and it happen in right way. But i want show after scroll up page 100px, means not want show right way, want to show after 100px scroll up page. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2):

This JS should work :)

**Javascript**

```
$(window).on('scroll',function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll >= 100){
        $('.nav').fadeOut();
    } else {
        if(!$('.nav').is(":visible")){
            $('.nav').fadeIn();
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9fbr320y/16/

Comment: I don't think it's just a matter of hiding/showing the scroll but also adding/removing the 'darkHeader' class

Comment: @Sofiene DJEBALI - hi thanks, but it's not like this.I mean my old show/hide navigation is ok, but i want to show/hide after 100px of page scroll position not on 0px.

Comment: @SofieneDJEBALI  - Thanks, Detail is: My old hide & showing should not change it's only show navigation menu when you scroll up page and it happen in right way. But i want show after scroll up page 100px, means not showing right way, want showing after 100px scroll up page. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

the `$(window).scrollTop()` returns the scroll amount from top in pixels, so simply write:

```
$(window).on('scroll',function() {    
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll > 100){
        $(".nav").addClass("darkHeader");
    } else {
        $(".nav").removeClass("darkHeader");
    } 
});
```

Comment: hi thanks, but it's not like this.I mean old show/hide navigation is ok, but i want to show/hide after 100px of page scroll position.